# greasemonkey script fires only once per page load

Tags: greasemonkey, pageload

I run a greasemonkey script with this URL :

```
// @include     https://www.younow.com*
// @exclude     https://www.younow.com/steven73*
// @grant       none
// ==/UserScript==
alert("HELLO");
```

My problem is that my script seems to be "disabled" on "internal" navigations, meaning when I run Firefox and the first site I load is the "steven73" page and after that page is loaded I click one of the "Trending Now" streamers (you see it on left top corner on the website) I want to get the messagebox but the msgbox doesn't appear, because the script is executed only "ONE TIME" when I visit the "younow" website the 1st time (except F5). It seems that "internal" navigations are blocking the execution of the script. How can I execute my script each time when clicking one of the "Trending Now" streamers (on the left top corner on the website) ?

Answer (score 0):

This site uses AJAX approach to update parts of the page without reloading it fully.
Whereas userscripts are automatically executed only on initial page load.

Add a listener for click event and run your code after a pause:

```
document.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    var trendingLink = e.target.closest('a.trending_image');
    if (trendingLink) {
        var stopTryingAt = Date.now() + 5000;
        var interval = setInterval(function() {
            if (document.querySelector('.player-main')) {
                clearInterval(interval);
                onPageUpdated();
            }
            if (Date.now() >= stopTryingAt) {
                clearInterval(interval);
            }
        }, 20);
    }
});

function onPageUpdated() {
    console.log('Boo!');
}
```

Or use [waitForKeyElements](https://gist.github.com/BrockA/2625891) function to wait until an element appears instead of using setInterval.

Comment: I've tested it on the thumbnail link so you may need to change the `a.trending_image` selector. Actually you can simply use 'a' to catch all link clicks.